# Jenkins Script to Restrict all builds to a given node

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson

We've recently added a second slave node to our Jenkins build environment running a different OS (Linux instead of Windows) for specific builds. Unsurprisingly, this means we need to restrict builds via the "Restrict where this project can be run" setting. However we have a lot of builds (100+) so the prospect of clicking through them all to change this setting manually isn't thrilling me.

Can someone provide a groovy script to achieve this via the Jenkins script console? I've used similar scripts in the past for changing other settings but I can't find any reference for this particular setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to figure out the script for myself based on previous scripts and the Jenkins source. Script is as follows:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.model.labels.*
import hudson.maven.*
import hudson.tasks.*
import hudson.plugins.git.*

hudsonInstance = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
allItems = hudsonInstance.allItems
buildableItems = allItems.findAll{ job -> job instanceof BuildableItemWithBuildWrappers }

buildableItems.each { item ->
  boolean shouldSave = false
  item.allJobs.each { job ->
    job.assignedLabel = new LabelAtom('windows-x86') 
  }
}
```

Replace 'windows-x86' with whatever your node label needs to be. You could also do conditional changes based on item.name to filter out some jobs, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [Jenkins Job-DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

which would allow you to create a job to alter your other jobs. This works by providing a build step in a groovy based DSL to modify other jobs.

This one here would add a label to the job 'xxxx'. I've cheated a bit by using the job itself as a template.

```
job{
  using 'xxxx'
  name 'xxxx'
  label 'Linux'
}
```

You might need to adjust it if some of you jobs are different types